# GEE: reducing CHIRPS-SPI by region and time. user memory limit problem

Tags: google-earth-engine, memory, reducers, spi

I found a [script](https://www.un-spider.org/advisory-support/recommended-practices/recommended-practice-drought-monitoring-spi/step-by-step) that calculates the SPI index for places and times of your choice from the CHIRPS data. Off the shelf, the code generates a couple of images (and maps) for each place-time combination for download.

I am trying to extend the script (starting line 667) to aggregate the image collection (including the SPI index) over districts in Uganda and to generate a table for export into drive. See my code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/12fe45c0da8a6984fa513d9e97a2186a).

Running the export task always fails due to “user memory limit exceeded”. Theoretically, that table should have something like 163 dates X 4 bands X 166 features (admin units) =  108232 entries. I already tried saving memory wherever possible, following the GEE debugging recommendations. In particular, I did so by:

1. only exporting part of the collection (i.e.
   ImageCollectionForExportMonthly)
2. disabling all print commands
3. simplifying feature complexity of the regions (line 672-674)
4. increasing tileScale to the max (16)

– yet still failing to run the export. I am unsure whether my code has a (some) mistake(s) or the operations are really exceeding the user limits.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the use of AOI as a clipping geometry.

The AOI is an entire table, the geometries of which contain a total of 905,014 points.  Clipping with that over lots of images means reprojecting the whole thing as a single geometry for every image, which takes a lot of memory.

You could do better with `clipToCollection`, but all of that is unnecessary, since you're specifying regions in the reduceRegion call anyway.

Delete all of the uses of AOI and it works fine.